# Best way to expand info in hover AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, expand, expandoobject

On mouse-over element must be expanded , on mouse-out must be collapsed. 
In this way this functions works very slowly (expanded files visible after 2 second)
Whats the fastest wey expand on mouseover and collapse in this situation ?

```
<li ng-repeat="sport in leftMenuPrematchSports track by sport.id">
   <div ng-mouseenter="openGame(sport)" ng-mouseleave="closeGame(sport)"> 
     <div ng-if="hover" ng-class="{'active': sport[sport.id].expanded}" mb-scrollbar"">

      // mb-scrollbar is custom style scrollbar directive
      //Info about sport

     </div>
   </div>
</li>

//Controller 

$scope.openGame = function(sport){  
       this.hover = true;
       this.expandLeftMenuPrematchSport(sport, null, null, false);
       this.selectSport(sport,!$scope.sport[sport.id].expanded);
}

$scope.closeGame= function(sport){  
       this.hover = false;
       this.expandLeftMenuPrematchSport(sport, null, null, false);
}
```

Images: 
.On mouseover : https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXqbJ.png

SITE DEMO : https://www.loungebet.com/#/sport/?type=0&sport=-12&competition=566&game=5967702
(In left side ,sports)

Comment: it's actually fast sometimes, it's only the site background processes causes the JS to delay

Comment: hmm,,there is no way do something to improve speed of expanding?

Comment: it's actually the whole site not the expanding, tried hovering other items, it's having a delay of 2-3secs before it hits the animation. You should check your codes.

Comment: It *seems like* the `expandLefMenuPrematchSport` function may be fetching data after the click occurs, and the menu is expanded but empty until the data is returned later.  You may want to pre-fetch data that is needed for these menus...

Comment: @Claies thanks for review . Ill try to fetch all element in loading

Comment: @Claies its take so many time ...

Comment: I don't know why your server is taking so long to return data, as you have provided no information regarding this process.  I didn't even provide an answer because all I can do is make a few *guesses* at what might be going on, based on what you provided.  it's not really even clear how much data you are getting for each menu section;  for the menu sections, you should only need a few fields...  This still all points back to you needing to review your app logic, and not being any bug with the angular codebase.